# Block inside of method doesn't return

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have to folowing method.

I want this method to return 1 if the user liked the page, or 0 if the user didn't.But it seems like the block is called before the function.

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Thank you!.

```
-(NSInteger) userWithId:(NSString *)fb_id likesPageWithID:(NSString *)page_id {

    __block NSInteger returnValue;
    NSString *fbGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes/%@",fb_id,page_id];
    NSLog(@"%@",fbGraphPath);
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:fbGraphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        } else {
            if([result count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
                returnValue = 0;

            } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);

                returnValue = 1;

                }
            }
    }];
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Try using NSNotification. This will surly help you in this case.

Comment: "the block is called before the function" Can you explain this a little better? Do you mean the block runs before the method returns? Do you mean the block runs before `NSLog` is called?...

Comment: Yes. the block runs asynchronously, so the method returns before the NsLog is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three ways to do this:

**Notification Center**

Like Apurv answer suggests, you can use notification centre to broadcast the result:

```
- (void)userWithId:(NSString *)fb_id likesPageWithID:(NSString *)page_id {

    __block NSInteger returnValue;
    NSString *fbGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes/%@",fb_id,page_id];
    NSLog(@"%@",fbGraphPath);
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:fbGraphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        } else {
            if([result count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
                returnValue = 0;

            } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);

                returnValue = 1;

                }
            }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"mynotif" object:nil userInfo:@{@"result":@(returnValue)}];
    }];
}
```

Personally, I wouldn't do this unless I needed to broadcast the value. Using notifications adds some unnecessary overhead.

**Condition**

This is the simplest to implement, and it doesn't change who you use this method, but is a bit overkill.

```
- (NSInteger)userWithId:(NSString *)fb_id likesPageWithID:(NSString *)page_id {

    __block NSInteger returnValue;
    NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition new];
    [condition lock];
    NSString *fbGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes/%@",fb_id,page_id];
    NSLog(@"%@",fbGraphPath);
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:fbGraphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        } else {
            if([result count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
                returnValue = 0;

            } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);

                returnValue = 1;

                }
            }
        [condition lock];
        [condition signal];
        [condition unlock];
    }];
    [condition wait];
    [condition unlock];
}
```

Also, this code will block the running thread. So the thread that calls this method can't be the same that runs the FB's completion handler.

**Blocks**

This is, in my opinion, the best.

```
- (void)userWithId:(NSString *)fb_id likesPageWithID:(NSString *)page_id withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSInteger))handler {

    __block NSInteger returnValue;
    NSString *fbGraphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes/%@",fb_id,page_id];
    NSLog(@"%@",fbGraphPath);
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:fbGraphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        } else {
            if([result count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);
                returnValue = 0;

            } else {
                    NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"data"]);

                returnValue = 1;

                }
            }
        handler(returnValue);
    }];
}
```

It's easy to use it to:

```
[var userWithId:fb_id likesPageWithID:page_id withCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    // use result for whatever you need
}];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and when i call the last method? how i would do that?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what i expected, it worked. And now I understood the idea of the blocks.

Comment: The some place you call it now. You just change it to use the new parameter.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How do I do the Block solution in swift? Please.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks work asynchronously. So, when you call `startWithGraphPath`, the execution goes to the next line directly. Your completion block will be called once the caller method finishes its execution. So, in general you should not return the value. But at the end of block, you should broadcast the notification with proper value encapsulated in it.

Comment: I know it will work, but i think there should be another way. I don't really like notifications

Comment: In that case you should pass your block in the argument of userWithId method. This block will be called when completion handler completes execution.

Comment: what block i should pass as an argument?

Comment: Blocks don't necessarily work asynchronously, though in this case they do.

Comment: Ok i got it, but, this is the first time i work with blocks. Can you show me an example, or a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Almost always the answer given by @Apurv will be correct, you'll do either of the following:

- Pass in a block that contains parameter(s) for the data you'd like to retrieve (best for one to one)
- Fire a notification (best for publish subscribe).

Though to answer your question directly, if you have an external library that provides asynchronous callbacks and you ***really would*** like to invoke it synchronously you can do the following:

**Option 1: Use a semaphore**

A semaphore halts execution until a signaled to proceed.

```
-(NSInteger) userWithId:(NSString *)fb_id likesPageWithID:(NSString *)page_id {

    dispatch_semaphore_t querySemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    __block NSInteger returnValue;        
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:fbGraphPath parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        returnValue = xyz; //calculate your return value
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(querySemaphore);


    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(querySemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return returnValue;
}
```

**Option 2: Use Runloop (hacky)**

If your block is calling back on the same thread/queue that the dispatch was done from, a deadlock will occur. One way to avoid this is to use the run loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //time-out
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
    if (returnValue)
    {
        return returnValue;
    }
}
return nil;
```

Comment: I always forget `dispatch_semaphore_t`. Please edit my answer to change the `NSCondition` for a `dispatch_semaphore_t`. I'd do it my self, but you deserve the credit ;)

Comment: :) Didn't know about NSCondition, so it gets my vote.